# Send email using c#

Tags: c#, smtpclient

I am trying to send email using C# but I am getting below error.

> Mailbox was unavailable. The server response was: Relay access denied. Please authenticate.

I am not sure why I am getting this error. Here, I am using smtp2go third party to send this email.

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("mail.smtp2go.com");

mail.From = new MailAddress("myemail@wraptite.com");
mail.To.Add("test1@gmail.com");
mail.Subject = "Test Email";
mail.Body = "Report";

//Attachment attachment = new Attachment(filename);
//mail.Attachments.Add(attachment);

SmtpServer.Port = 25;
SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("me", "password");
//SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;

SmtpServer.Send(mail);
```

Comment: 1) which line is throwing the error? (don't just assume that it is the last line).  2) Are you sure that those are valid credentials for that SmtpServer?

Comment: Not programming issue. Perhaps you need to use smtp2go SSL/TLS port with credentials.

Comment: Try SSL on port 465: https://support.smtp2go.com/hc/en-gb/articles/223087627-SMTP-Settings

Comment: Also, why have you disabled SSL?  I'm not familiar with the smtp2go services, but they might require it.  Try re-enabling it.

Comment: Oops, missed the new comments...

Comment: I enabled the SSL and changed the port to 465 but now I am getting the operation is time out. User name and password is right
Thank you for help

Answer (score 2):

I've tried your code and it work fine.
But in my case, to use the smtp server, from(email address of sender) must use the same domain to authenticate.(but gmail is available to this [Send emails from a different address or alias](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/22370?hl=en))

So, If your SMTP server connect to `smtp2go.com`, try as below.

```
SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("mail.smtp2go.com");
mail.From = new MailAddress("myemail@smtp2go.com");
```

Or if you need to use service of smtp2go, it would be better use rest [API](https://apidoc.smtp2go.com/documentation/?_ga=2.126442889.589998117.1572221861-552125480.1572221861#/README).

---

#### Here is updated by your comment when **using gmail**.

Gmail required [secure app access](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en). that's a reason why code is not work.
So, there is two options for this.

#### 1. Update your gmail account security

(origin idea from here : [C# - 이메일 발송방법](https://insurang.tistory.com/330))

Go to [here](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en) and `turn on` "Less secure app access". after doing this your code will work.(it works)

#### 2. Using "Google API Client Library for .NET."

I think this is not so easy, check this out, I found an answer related with this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35203152/smtpclient-in-c-sharp-using-smtp-gmail-com857-with-googles-2-step-verification)

Comment: Second this.  I've seen the same problem--some mail servers will not permit you to send an e-mail with an origination address different than the account you sign in with.  Others don't care.

Comment: Hi,
I changed my code to send email with my gmail account but still I am getting below error.
Error: The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was 5.5.1 Authentication Required.

Answer (score 0):

```
#region SendMail
            //Mail Setting
            string EmailSubject = "EmailSubject";
            string EmailBody = "EmailBody";
            try
            {
                string FromAddress = "abc@gmail.com";
                string EmailList = "abc1@gmail.com";
                string EmailServer = "ipofemailserver";
                using (var theMessage = new MailMessage(FromAddress, EmailList))
                {
                    // Construct the alternate body as HTML.
                    string body = "EmailBody";
                    ContentType mimeType = new System.Net.Mime.ContentType("text/html");
                    // Add the alternate body to the message.
                    AlternateView alternate = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(body, mimeType);
                    theMessage.AlternateViews.Add(alternate);
                    theMessage.Subject = EmailSubject;
                    theMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
                    SmtpClient theSmtpServer = new SmtpClient();
                    theSmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password");
                    theSmtpServer.Host = EmailServer;
                    theSmtpServer.Send(theMessage);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string AppPath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
                string ErrorPath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "File\\Error\\";
                string OutFileTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
                using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(ErrorPath + OutFileTime + ".txt", true, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8))
                {
                    sw.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString() + "：");
                    sw.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                    sw.Close();
                }
            }
            #endregion
```